# Can I run Xubuntu or Lubuntu operating system on Pentium 4-630 single core processor (3.00 GHz) with 4 GB RAM?

Tags: system-installation

- Processor: Intel Pentium 4 -630 CPU 3.00GHz. (Single Core)
- RAM: DDR2 4 GBytes

Comment: Yes you might do this, but I would suggest to use Debian instead, because it performs better on older hardware -> https://www.debian.org

Comment: Is this processor 64 bit?

Comment: It will work, and Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS will work too. Pentium 4 is still alive. Give it a SSD and will fly fast.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try. It will probably run, and probably even better than some old Windows xp/Vista kinda stuff. It is technically not supported, but I have a pentium 4 myself and it even ran Ubuntu 19.10. It won't run fast though, since more than 2 cores is better, and your pc probably doesn't have ssd.